# How to do I seperate approvals in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I recently created an Account Request Tool in Power Automate. I have Account 1, Account 2, and account 3. They are all three different SharePoint List under the same site. However when I go to the Power Automate Approval section they are in the same Approval section.

I need to know how can I show Approval just for Account 1 as well for Accounts 2 and 3?

Comment: As of right now, I personally don't understand what you're asking for.  Are you able to provide some screenshots or something?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for your issue is to create separate child flows and merge it into the parent flow. Below is the link on how to create child flow.

[How to create child flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows)